# did + past participle

Tags: tense, emphasis

I have stumbled across such phrase in the TV show *House*:

> The police investigated what they saw, not what they didn't saw.

My question is why is the second form of the verb "see" is used in the second part of the sentence, but not in the first form as it should be used in past simple after "did"? It is supposed to be didn't see, isn't it? Is it some kind of emphasis? And in which cases can it be used?

Comment: As far as I can tell, that phrasing is wrong. The second use of the verb should be **see**. Perhaps there's some context for its deliberate misuse.

Answer (score 1):

In standard English "didn't saw" is an error.

There is a verb "to saw" meaning to cut wood with a saw. "I didn't saw the timber, I cut it with a knife" is correct.   That does not appear to be the verb used here.

It is possible that the grammar error is done on purpose to show a that a character isn't skilled at speaking English. Or it may be a joke in some way.

However, it is not correct English.